# how to access subscribeToMore when using ApolloClient.query() manually onClick

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-apollo

I have a scenario when where I am calling a gql query manually using ApolloClient.query(), but the prob is this way I dont get subscribeToMode in result data ... running the query automatically on component mount works fine...

any idea about how to use  subscribeToMode in on manual query?

**this is what Iam trying to achieve...**

```
this.props.client.query({ query:getPost, variables:{id:100} })
      .then(data => {
        this.subscription = data.data.subscribeToMore({
         // subscription code here...
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

let me explain the scenario..

1) I have a request form filed and submitted, records goes to the db, I got _id back... and now waiting for the approval of request on the same screen..

2) now someone else on other screen got the new entry and just pressed the approved button, rec updated in DB..

3) now I want the approval to be shows on the screen... this should all happen instantly.. or request will expire in lets say 1 min...

now my prob is 3, how can I get the approval update on the same screen... dont want to use another component.. the recordAdd is called through ApolloClient.query()
what I need to do it after the AddRec is executed successfully and received _id, i need to set a subscription on it... but it dosnt work unless I run in under **ComponentWillReceiveProps**()

Comment: is it the same known `subscribe()` but with the original query passed in automatically?

Comment: nop... nothing is done automatically... just added some scenario details... check it plz

Comment: I mean `<Query query={query}>{(subscribeToMore)}` works the same wsay as `this.props.client.subscribe()` do but it also  automatically passes related query to subscribe for.

Comment: my client is react-native app.. will it work the same way on it ?

Comment: sorry guys I figured it out... it was indeed a stupid question ...  I got it working with subscribe() , @skyboyer thanks for the tip...

Comment: one thing btw... I couldnt find the proper API doc for subscribe() function... can anyone suggest me a link please.. !

Comment: have you seen official docs? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client.html#ApolloClient.subscribe I'm not sure if there is more detailed version anywhere

Comment: @skyboyer bless you man! ... I wonder how did I miss that .. :)